# Is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion

The purpose of the Meta for any site is to discus a wide range of subjects relating to the main site, including whether or not questions are on or off topic. So my question is this:

Is this question off topic?

**Edit:**
For those of you who want the question link I'm referencing:

[Is this question off topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/639/5426)

Comment: Either I'm missing something, you forgot to link to the question, or I'm going to vote to close as "Too meta". :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its too confusing for non-sophisticated users, and is there for discriminatory.

Comment: I see no point to this and yes it would be considered offtopic as it is not asking anything related to our site or se. [Questions soliciting extended discussions are a no no.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This more of a hypothetical question thus it really would be better suited to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com. However it the broadest scene, yes it is (kind of) on topic.

Quoting from https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

> Meta Blender Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Blender Stack Exchange rather than discussing blender itself.

So yes, asking if a question is on or off topic is proper for the meta. However posting a question on the meta asking if itself is on or off topic is borderline spam.
I say "spam" because if you look at the flag and close reasons given, spam with its "It is not useful or relevant" line is the closest.